# How to place a header on top of centered div? (html/css)

Tags: html, css, header, center

I'm new at coding and I've managed to figure out some things, but this one is bugging me deeply as I can't seem to find a solution.

I have an horizontal & vertically centered div on a page. I want to place a header on top of it, without decentering the main div.

How it looks like now (both are centered as a whole):
[image: both are centered as a whole.]

How I want it to look (yellow is centered, blue header on top):
[image: yellow is centered, blue header on top.]

..
Basic code:

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.main {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="main">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some code, please... What have you tried?

Comment: Please at least provide a basic example of your markup and CSS. Still, quick shot: give the centered div a negative margin of the height of the header (if it's a fixed height) or set the header to `display: fixed`. However, it really depends on the circumstances what's the best method to achieve this, so please provide some code.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I accidentally posted without the code. Just updated it with a basic example and also 2 images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely not the best answer, but it's a start.
Baisically I centered the container using [this method](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/). Then I added the -50px to the top attribute of the container (half of the header height), moving the container 50px upwards, making the content div totally centered again. This solution should work on most newer browsers, but has some "limits" [more here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

HTML

```
<div class="centered-container">
    <div class="header">
        header stuff
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Content stuff here.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #600;
}

.centered-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 600px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}

.content {
    height:300px;
    background:teal;
}
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/flynorc/nk6w2mpq/).

I made the content 600px wide and 300px high and header 100px high, just so it is easier to see.
The negative margin

Comment: I want the header to be on top of the main div, and keep the main div in the same position as it would be without a header... (The main div has an image so I'd like to be the only thing centered on the page. The header is going to have a logo on it, so I wanted it to be above, and not be in a centered container along with the main.)

Comment: does your header have known dimensions (in your example 1000px * 100px)?

And the centered div, should it always bee 1000px * 500px?
what should the behaviour be when window is smaller than 1000px*600px?

Comment: Since I'm new at this, I thought I shouldn't start learning by considering responsive design right away. Should I do this from the very beginning as I learn? Use percentages or define different dimensions according to the window size?

Comment: @Teresa it really depends on what you want to build, but for the majority of the projects nowdays i would say responsive is almost a must. But if you want to take it slow and just play arround  you can try to take it step by step. I will update my answer to include a working demo of what you want do to, but I have to say it is most likely not the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for this :-) it's definitely a start.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Handles the init code(javascript,css,links) and style references -->
<!-- Also, use body and head tags (THEY ARE IMPORTANT) -->
<head>
    <style>
        /** Web browsers load whatever is in the <head> tag FIRST
        */

        .outer {
          display: table;
          position: absolute;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .middle {
          display: table-cell;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }

        /* You can use "margin: 0 auto;" to center this object.
        * No need for left and right margin centering.
        *
        * Also, set the position to be relative then try adding your heading object
        */
        .header {
          width: 1000px;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: blue;
          margin: 0 auto;
          position: relative;
        }

        /* You don't need the margin to be 0 auto on both right and left
        * if you have the width 100%
        */

        .main {
          width: 100%;
          height: 500px;
          background-color: yellow;
          margin: 0;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<!-- Everything In Body Tag is style elements or skeletal HTML (div's, span's, format)-->
<!-- Place the heading OUTSIDE of the header element (in the outer div) this shouldn't alter the position of the 
header. -->
<body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="main">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```